# WordPress - get_permalink return wrong URL

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I've got a weird issue - I have a custom post type called events. All my 'events' single posts are visible under URL:

http://mycompany.com/events

It's OK. The listing is also correct. But I've approach weird issue:
- When I create new event post with future publish date (so scheduling the post) in the admin area I have pretty link: like mycompany.com/events/fabio-concert-2017
- When I'm listing all posts of events in a page it return ugly link like: 
mycompany.com?post_type=events&p=10567

How to make scheduled/future posts with pretty links also?

Comment: What Permalink Settings you have set?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer for why it happened.
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/get_permalink-returns-default-link/

Answer (score 0):

You Need to know following Things.

1. Mask URL.
2. Real URL.

**Mask URL** is just created from HTAccess of Links.

**Real URL** is a exact URL of Wordpress Data.

The WordPress running the real URL and showing a Mask URL in a frondend.
In Your Case,

```
mycompany.com?post_type=events&p=10567 -> Real URL.
mycompany.com/events/fabio-concert-2017 -> Mask URL.
```

If You are run these both URL in Your Browser, you will get same result only. So No worry about it. Because **get_permalinks($product)** Will return Real URL of the Product.